# Javascript conditional hiding and showing

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, show-hide

Hello guys I'm confused with javascript code, I want a program that gets the input from the user, and if that input matches a specific value like 1234 I want it to hide part of the form. E.g.

```js
var x=document.getElementById('pin').value;

    function hidden() {
      if (x.value=1234){
       document.getElementById('pin').style.display="none";
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" name="pin" placeholder="Please Enter Your Pin" id="pin">
<button onclick="hidden()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Assuming this is representative. Move the x assignment inside the function. Currently it is set at page load and will always be empty. You also don't need to call value on x, it already is the value.

Comment: `=` is assignment

Comment: @Eng could you provide more details? Is your javascript snippet executing? You might want to start by wrapping it in a script tag. Also, what part of the form do you want to hide exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var x=document.getElementById('pin');

function checkPin() {
  if (x.value == "1234"){
      x.style.display="none";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="pin" placeholder="Please Enter Your Pin" id="pin" />
<button onclick="checkPin()">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Thansk Bro! You

Comment: @EngImranAdbullah if you need, you can run the snippet again ("Run code snippet") and if this solved your problem you should [accept it as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The value is not a native number, but a string, and you're assigning in the conditional check. Instead of '=' use '==' or '==='.

Try this:

```
function hidden() {
  var x = document.getElementById('pin').value;
  if (x === '1234'){
    document.getElementById('pin').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```